# multiple delimiters and sum in awk

Tags: awk, command-line, sum, text-processing

can someone help with some the use of awk in command line to have the sum of columns by date
i have the following format

```
date numbersofOK numbersofKO's
2022/09/27::15:39:00    OK's=8  KO's=15
2022/09/27::16:38:52    OK's=8  KO's=12
2022/09/28::23:37:33    OK's=0  KO's=0
2022/09/28::00:37:22    OK's=1  KO's=2
```

i would like to have the sum of OK, sum of KOs for every day like the following:

```
date    numbers of OK    numbers of KO's
2022/09/27    16    27
2022/09/28    4    2
```

thanks you

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried code in your question, not my downvote btw, thank you.

Comment: @didisan : do ur own homework

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
2022/09/27::15:39:00    OK's=8  KO's=15
2022/09/27::16:38:52    OK's=8  KO's=12
2022/09/28::23:37:33    OK's=0  KO's=0
2022/09/28::00:37:22    OK's=1  KO's=2
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";FS="[:[:space:]=]*"}{days[$1];ok[$1]+=$6;ko[$1]+=$8}END{for(d in days){print d,ok[d],ko[d]}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
2022/09/27 16 27
2022/09/28 1 2
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that about desired [order of array traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html), as dates in `YYYY/MM/DD` might be compared lexicographically and give excepted result I inform GNU `AWK` to sort alphabetically on indices and that field separator (`FS`) is zero or more (`*`) colon or whitespace or equals sign. For each row I store seen day (1st field) as indice of value days and increase values in `ok` and `ko` under key being that day by appropriate value which is 6th and 8th field respectively. After I line are processed I do traverse days and `print` key of it and corresponding values. You might elect to not set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` if you are accepting any order of records in output.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick awk:

```
awk '{ d = substr($1,1,10); ok[d]+=substr($2,6); ko[d]+=substr($3,6) }
     END{for(d in ok) print d,ok[d],ko[d] }' file
```

If you want to keep the original order, and your file is already sorted properly, you can use:

```
awk '{ d = substr($1,1,10) }
     (d != t) && t { print t, ok, ko ; ok=ko=0 }
     { ok+=substr($2,6); ko+=substr($3,6); t=d }
     END{ print t, ok, ko  }' file
```